# Bigcommerce Webhook Callback - Send 200 response in Guzzle

Tags: php, bigcommerce, webhooks, guzzle

I'm working with Bigcommerce API to create an application. I am using Webhooks to call my script every time an order has taken place.

Bigcommerce wants me to send back a 200 signal to let them know the request was received OK.

I am using Guzzle and this is my first time.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is the code I'm using to create the webhook:

```
// Send a request to register a web hook
$http2 = new Client('https://api.bigcommerce.com', array(
$request = $http2->post('/'.$store_hash.'/v2/hooks', null, array(
    'scope' => 'store/order/*',
    'headers' => array(
        'X-Custom-Auth-Header' => '{secret_auth_password}'
    ),
    'destination' => 'https://example.com/process_order.php',
    'is_active' => true
));
$response = $request->send();
```

When I receive a call from Bigcommerce to: https://example.com/process_order.php

I need to send a 200 OK as per: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/webhooks-getting-started
See heading: Respond to webhook callbacks

Am I to send the 200 as a POST request, or as a header in a GET request?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that tool, but you should probably return 200 after successfully handling the request in `process_order.php`. (200 is the default HTTP success return value, so you may not even have to do anything special.)

Comment: I guess I will try not sending a response and see how it goes. Thanks Chris